# How to connect to Phoenix From Apache Spark 2.X Using Java

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-phoenix, hdp

Surprisingly , couldn't find any up to date **`JAVA`** document in the web for this . The 1 or 2 examples in the entire World Wild Web is too old. I came up with the following which fails with error '`Module not Found org.apache.phoenix.spark`' , but That module is part of the Jar for Sure . I don't think following approach is right because it is copy - paste from different examples, and loading a module like this is a bit anti pattern , as we already have the package as part of the jar. Please show me the right way.

Note- Please do Scala or Phython example , They are easily available over net,

```
public class ECLoad {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Create a SparkContext to initialize
        String warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath();
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("ECLoad")
                .master("local")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
                .getOrCreate();

        spark.conf().set("spark.testing.memory", "2147480000");         // if you face any memory issue
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.sqlContext().read().format("org.apache.phoenix.spark.*").option("table",
                "CLINICAL.ENCOUNTER_CASES").option("zkUrl", "localhost:2181").load();
        df.show();
    }

}
```

I'm trying to run it as

```
spark-submit --class "encountercases.ECLoad" --jars phoenix-spark-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar,phoenix-core-5.0.0-HBase-2.0.jar --master local ./PASpark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and I get following error -

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration`

I see required jars are already at the suggested path and hbase-site.xml symlink exixsts.[image]

Comment: Which hadoop distro+version do you use?

Comment: HDP 3.0 . but i don't think it got anything to do with that

Answer (score 0):

Before getting phoenix working with spark, you will need to setup the environment for spark so that it knows how to access phoenix/hbase.

1. First create a symbolic link to `hbase-site.xml`
   `ln -s /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml /etc/spark2/conf/hbase-site.xml`
   Alternatively you can add this file while creating spark session or in spark defaults.
2. You will need to add jars under `/usr/hdp/current/phoenix-client/` to driver as well as executor class path. Parameters to be set: `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath`
3. This step is trivial and could easily be translated into java/scala/python/R, above 2 steps are critical for it to work as those setup env:

`val df = sqlContext.load("org.apache.phoenix.spark",Map("table" -> "CLINICAL.ENCOUNTER_CASES", "zkUrl" -> "localhost:2181"))`

Refer to: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/179762/how-to-connect-to-phoenix-tables-using-spark2.html

Comment: I'm using HDP 3.0 and I see step 1 and 2 already been done there by default

Comment: Apparently not. Looks like you have a new error which wasn't there before the edit. The error indicates missing hbase-client jar from spark classpath.